# codedu ui gives access is denied error for the program under test

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I dont know if anyone ever come up with this situation but today I come up with this weird situation with codedu, nothing works when I run tests. Today when I come to office , installed AccessDatabaseEngine  for datadriven test and start a testMethod, none of my records are running, I took a new record and also not working. Restart VS or restart PC doesnt help. Please somebody help me getting out of this situation. When I run a test, it bring up the already open application (UAT) but can not play.

I am not sure whether its cause but I installed AccessDatabaseEngine before running any test. I tried to uninstall it but when I look at applications I cant see where its placed..

I noticed that I doesnt record all, I tried to record a new test. It throws "Access is Denied", while capturing the application

and it gives Control not found error when I try to run

I found some pages for same error
I checked CodedUITestBuilder config file and I see this line was commented and I changed it but this did not fixed.

```
   <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
```

I also tried changing properties of CodedUITestBuilder.exe but again same result

[Coded UI Test Builder fails to generate code for recorded action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645903/coded-ui-test-builder-fails-to-generate-code-for-recorded-action)

Answer (score 0):

Its fixed after I uninstalled the AccessDatabaseEngine . I installed it by clicking same exe. I should not install it because its too old, that is obvious with its icon.